# MongoDB How to return exactly N documents within a specified date range with required 'start at' and 'end at' points

Tags: mongodb

```js
var fromMs = 1503641711307;
var toMs = 1506224754623;
var intervals = 200;
var intervalsInt = isNaN(parseInt(intervals)) ? 500 : parseInt(intervals);
var intervalMs = Math.round(Number((toMs - fromMs) / intervalsInt));

db.mycollection.aggregate(
  [{
    $match: {
      timestamp: {
        $gte: new Date(fromMs),
        $lt: new Date(toMs)
      },
      source: 'graphs',
      typedata: 'rainfall_rate',
    }
  }, {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $subtract: [
          "$timestamp",
          {
            "$mod": [{
              "$subtract": ["$timestamp", new Date("1970-01-01")]
            }, intervalMs]
          }
        ]
      },
      "timestamp": {
        "$first": "$timestamp"
      },
      "source": {
        "$first": "$source"
      },
      "pair": {
        "$first": "$typedata"
      }
    }
  }])
```

The code above will return from mycollection exactly N = 200 documents from all documents in the collection with a date range starting from 1503641711307 and ending at 1506224754623.

The problem is that the 200 returned documents will NOT necessarily start exactly at 1503641711307 and end exactly at 1506224754623. Due to the mod calculation the start document will be most likely -after- 1503641711307 and the last document will be -before- 1506224754623.

Is there any way to always make sure that in the returned results there is always a document with start timestamp very close to or exactly at 1503641711307 and and a document with an end timestamp very close to or exactly at 1506224754623?

(I am including --'very close to'-- in my question since there may be documents not always at the specified timestamp in the collection, but the start and end timestamps in this case should be as close as possible to the specified range)

Comment: Are you sure you have document with timestamp of **exactly** `1503641711307`? The ending timestamp will always be less than `1506224754623` since you used `$lt` instead of `$lte` in the `$match` stage.

Comment: Thanks, actually it is not the problem of $lt or $lte, but your suggestion helped me realize the problem. The problem is namely the fact that this is a grouping by 'buckets' generated by the $mod calculation on each timestamp where the last timestamp to match a particular 'bucket' is the final result, so the start point will always be obscured by some later value, my only problem is that in the last 'bucket' the last value to fall in should be the point - 1506224754623, as it is the last one - or if such a time stamp does not exist some timestamp very near - but this is not the case.